# Unable to properly configure systemjs-builder with gulp

Tags: javascript, angular, gulp, systemjs, systemjs-builder

I'm trying to generate a static bundle of my angular 2 app (my goal is to have a single minified js file to import with a script tag without systemjs). My app has the following (simplified) structure:

```
MyProject/
    app/
        monitoring/
            a.ts
            b.ts
        terminals/
            a.ts
            b.ts
        main.ts
        app.module.ts
...
```

This is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "__dist__"
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "!node_modules/**"
  ]
}
```

This one the systemjs config:

```
(function () {

    var DEFAULT_PACKAGE_CONFIG = {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    };

    System.config({
        paths: {
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        map: {
            app: '__dist__',
            monitoring: '__dist__/monitoring',
            terminals: '__dist__/terminals',
            statistics: '__dist__/statistics',
            references: '__dist__/references',

            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',

            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'primeng': 'npm:primeng',
            'wijmo': 'scripts/vendor',
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api'
        },
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            primeng: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            wijmo: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            monitoring: DEFAULT_PACKAGE_CONFIG,
            terminals: DEFAULT_PACKAGE_CONFIG,
            statistics: DEFAULT_PACKAGE_CONFIG,
            references: DEFAULT_PACKAGE_CONFIG,
            'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
                main: './index.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });

})();
```

...and finally my gulp task:

```
gulp.task('bundle:js', function () {
    var builder = new SystemJsBuilder('.', './systemjs.config.js');
    return builder
        .buildStatic('__dist__/app/main.js', buildFolder + '/bundle.js');
});
```

...but when I run it, I get:

```
> Error on fetch for __dist__/app/monitoring.js at
> file:///MyProject/__dist__/app/monitoring.js  Loading
> __dist__/app/app.module.js    Loading __dist__/app/main.js    ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/MyProject/__dist__/app/monitoring.js'
```

...it seems it's ignoring subfolders under "app"... why? How can I fix this error?

Comment: Did you get solution?

Answer (score 0):

It actually looks like the problem is not in ignoring `app` directory but rather in your configuration.

You have:

```
System.config({
    packages: {
        monitoring: {
            main: './index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    ...
```

So I guess somewhere in your code you import `monitoring` which is automatically translated to `monitoring.js` because of the `defaultExtension` and therefore it throws an error because this file doesn't exist.

Comment: The settings for "monitoring" package are required for systemjs during development (and it works fine), otherwise it tries to load monitoring.js as I'm facing during the gulp compilation... in the source code imports are like this one: `import {DashboardComponent, AvailabilityComponent, AlertsComponent} from "./monitoring";` ...so I really don't understand what is wrong and how to fix :(

Comment: You don't have to use the same SystemJS config for both development and production. If you're sure you can handle loading the dependency in the browser and you're just unable to compile it you can use `build: false` option on particular resources. See https://github.com/systemjs/builder#ignore-resources

Comment: actually, it seems that the problem is the multiple import... if I define a single import for each component in the package it compiles without errors

Comment: @daveoncode Then maybe in `map` you could use `monitoring*` to match everything in this package.